# jquery post leaving out JSON values on post

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post

I have read a few similar questions, but no one seems to have asked about this specifically. I am sending a JSON object I know has the properties I want, but one of them disappears fromt he body durint a `$.post()` request. I have the following form, I know that the DOM ids are correct and that their `.val()`s are there, because I console log the json object before sending it as a parameter to `authenticate(user)`:

Here is an example for completeness:

```js
const authenticate = (user) => {
 console.log(user);
  $.post("http://localhost:8080/auth",user)
  .done(
    (data,status,xhr) => {
        console.log(data.user+"---user---");
      }
    ).fail(xhr => console.log(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).message));
  }
}

$('#login_form').on('submit', event => {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log({email:$('#username').val(),password:$('#password').val()});
  authenticate({email:'user@email.com',password:$('#password').val()});
});
```

```html
<form id="login_form" onsubmit="false">
                        <label for="username">Email</label>
                        <input id="username" name="username" placeholder="jimmy@john.com" type="email" class="form-control" required autofocus>                        

                        <label for="password">Password</label>
                        <input id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" type="password" class="form-control" required>                         
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" style="margin-top:10px">Log in</button>





<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```
{email:$('#username').val(),password:$('password').val()}
```

But I have tried replacing them with string values of a real user, and I can see that the `.val()`s are there in the console log. What I am seeing in the beowser's dev tools is that the post request is sending this as the body:

```
{email:"",password:"password"}
```

where it definitely is passing the right object, but the email field is either empty or a blank string. I have tried stringifying the object and sending it as a template literal, and I have tried setting the `$.post()` datatype to JSON, but nothing seems to make it parse the email, so I get a 400 back from the server's authenticator for missing credentials. I have exhausted every path I know to try, and not found someone with this issue on Google. Pls halp, and as always, thanks!

Comment: Stupid question, here `authenticate({email:'user@email.com',password:$('#password').val()});` why are you using `email:'user@email.com'`

Comment: That is just a remenant of my testing to see if it was due to the `.val()` being the issue, I will replace it with `$('#username').val()` but it should produce the same result

Comment: ohk cool.. `console.log(user);` what does it prints?

Comment: it also prints the correct object with the email and password present

Comment: Here is the exact console log from authenticate with the jquery values from the form this is from `console.log(user);` inside of the `authenticate(user)` function:
 `Object { email: "user@email.com", password: "123456" }`
And int he Form data param of the post request, it shows both email and password as attributes, but only password has a value.

Comment: ok.. can you plz create minimal code to show the problem, you can exclude tokens and all

Comment: okay it is minimal now, where you can see the error is in browser dev tools, the post url doesn't even matter, and it doesn't matter what strings you use as values for `email` and `password`, just look at the request params.

Comment: i understand given code is minimal, I didnt mean to remove icode from post but it is not useful to understand the problem origin.. maybe some other code would be useful

Comment: I added the login form for completeness, but this code will fully duplicate the problem, so I do not see exactly what you mean the problem is that `$.post('http://url.com', user)` where it is fully known that `user = {email:'string',password:'anotherstring'}` is sending nothing for the `'string'`

Comment: I think I got you confused, I meant if you could create a jsFiddle to showcase the problem with minimal code

Answer (score 0):

here is the working example, seems you were using same name for const & function

```js
$('#login_form').on('submit', event => {
  event.preventDefault();
  
  authenticate({
    email: $('#username').val(),
    password: $('#password').val()
  });
});

function authenticate(user){
    console.log(user);
    $.post("http://localhost:8080/auth", user)
      .done(
        (data, status, xhr) => {
          console.log(data.user + "---user---");
        }
      ).fail(xhr => console.log(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).message));
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="login_form" onsubmit="false">
  <label for="username">Email</label>
  <input id="username" name="username" placeholder="jimmy@john.com" type="email" class="form-control" required autofocus>

  <label for="password">Password</label>
  <input id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" type="password" class="form-control" required>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" style="margin-top:10px">Log in</button>

</form>
```

Comment: Okay, so I ficured out it was due to there being two event listeners for the login form ... also my function definition is fine in es6

Comment: my definition is es6 shorthand for `const authenticate = function(user) {}`

Comment: ohk.. but when I copied code the code was `function authenticate(user){ const authenticate = (user) =>`

Comment: well, thanks anyway for your help, I will be pulling this post in a few hours.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all, I will probably be pulling this down soon because it was just one of those "i'm an idiot" things. I had another event listener that I forgot to delete that was causing the issue. I knew something was up because when I posted my jsFiddle smippet, it worked...so there is nothing wrong with my using const in an es6 function definition. The correct listener was the one I posted:

```
$('#login_form').on('submit', event => {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log({email:$('#username').val(),password:$('#password').val()});
  authenticate({email:$('#username').val(),password:$('#password').val()});
});
```

But there was another one that had the wrong `DOM` id `$('#email).val()`:

```
$('#login_form').on('submit', event => {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log({email:$('#email').val(),password:$('#password').val()});
  authenticate({email:$('#email').val()',password:$('#password').val()});
});
```

Don't be dumb like me, read before you ask...